# permission_required for user who only users who are part of a group ,in view based class

Tags: django

Based on a tutorial,i have a view with a restriction on the display of data, based on a permission of the form "book.can_view" in class BookDetailView

This works, but the probleme are every user  not have access to the view I'd like to do the same thing but using the group name. . I would like only users who are part of a group named "premium" to have access to this page

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

from django.http import HttpResponse

from catalog.models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre
from accounts.models import CustomUser

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView


class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    paginate_by = 10
    #permission_required = 'catalog.view_book'


def index(request):    

    # Generate counts of some of the main objects
    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()

    # Available books (status = 'a')
    num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(
        status__exact='a').count()

    # The 'all()' is implied by default.
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()

    context = {
        'num_books': num_books,
        'num_instances': num_instances,
        'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
        'num_authors': num_authors,

    }

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)


class BookDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    """Generic class-based detail view for a book."""
    model = Book
    template_name = "catalog/permission_required.html"
    permission_required = 'book.can_view'# change this line ?


class AuthorListView(ListView):
    """Generic class-based list view for a list of authors."""
    model = Author
    paginate_by = 10


class AuthorDetailView(DetailView):
    """Generic class-based detail view for an author."""
    model = Author
```

thank for help

Answer (score 0):

I see it more or less like this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class BookDetailView(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "catalog/permission_required.html"

    def test_func(self):
        premium_group = Group.objects.filter(name = "premium") # or get
        if self.request.user in premium_group:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ttt, the code you told me

```
def test_func(self):
        premium_group = Group.objects.filter(name = "premium") # or get
        if self.request.user in premium_group:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

restricts access to all users, and i have page 403 , even the one who has the right to the "premium" group and even the admin, this sends you to the error page.